# Errors in application after updating to SSRS 2016 (Object doesn't support property or method)

Tags: .net, wpf, reporting-services

We have a WFP app (no source code) that hosts SSRS reports in a separate window. 
The window has several buttons and registers at least one event (determined because of the error message). It all worked fine on SSRS 2014, we upgraded to get away from the print driver requirement. In our environment the print driver distribution is troublesome. End users are not local admins.

When the report page opens we receive 2 errors and then the standard Prev, Next, print buttons are not displayed.

Errors are

> Object doesn't support property or method "addEventListener" Code 0
>   URL
>   http://SSRSServer/ReportServer_SSRS2016/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=13.0.1601.5&Name=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.RendererResources.jquery.min.js

Then

> 'jQuery' is undefined Code 0 URL
>   http://SSRSServer/ReportServer_SSRS2016/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=13.0.1601.5&Name=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.RendererResources.jqueryui.min.js

Things to note.
The report opens perfectly if the url is pasted into an IE 11 address bar.

http://SSRSServer/ReportServer_SSRS2016/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/IntelliPERMIT/Opsuite/rptclrClearanceCertificate&rc:LinkTarget=_blank&rc:Parameters=false&rs:Command=Render&rs:ClearSession=true&SerialNumber=33615

And the server host both SSRS 2014 and 2016 native mode side by side.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try these.

Click the Close button to close the error message. Find Internet Explorer Tools. Choose Compatibility View Settings. Add URL of site, accept changes and Close. Refresh the page and try to open the site now.
If the issue is still existing, you can try to change the settings in Internet Explorer and check.

Open Internet Explorer, click on Tools. Click on Internet Options, click Advanced tab. Make sure there is a check mark for these options:

Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)
Disable script debugging (Other)
Uncheck Display notification about every script error. Click Apply and OK. Restart the Internet Explorer and check the issue.
Try to disable enhanced protected mode and check.

Click the Tools icon in Internet Explorer. Go to Internet Options, click Advanced tab and select the Security section and uncheck the check box beside Enable Enhanced Protected Mode (requires restarting Internet Explorer). Click on Apply and then click OK.

Also try to add the websites to trusted sites list and check.

Open Internet Explorer, click on Tools and then click on Internet Options. Click on the Security tab. Now click on Trusted sites and then click on sites button. Type the URL of the website in the text box and click on the Add button . When you’re done, click on Close.

Comment: The problem wasn't with IE. It was with the WPF application as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the hosting application design.

In short. If a WPF application is written to interact with SSRS 2008, including hosting SSRS reports, paginating and printing, it likely won't work with SSRS 2016 due to changes in the API.

This issue arose attempting to circumvent the SSRS 2014 activeX print driver requirement. the solution to that was to use the MS ActiveX installer service.

So we are stuck with 2014.